# EXCEL - Search formula with multiple criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Do you know any way to write a formula for vlookup/indexmatch which will look for first result other than "null" for "aaaa", and then for bbb etc?

I was trying to do that with using multiple if/offsets etc, but its not working.
[image]

Is it even possible (there can be one row with "aaa" but also 10 on even more).

Comment: What do you need and what have you done so far?

Comment: You want to find the first non-null value(`Col B`) for each unique value in `Col A`?

Comment: Try a filter or even a Pivot Table

Comment: @newacc2240 so far I made tons of long formulas based on if/offsets/indexmatch/vlookups etc.

KacireeSoftware yes, thats is. And "aaa" and "bbb" is value.

Ron Rosenfeld Cannot use pivot, it's just for simple excel template to do calculations based on tons of data and tons of other formulas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following array formula returns the first entry in column `B` where it is not `null` and also where column `A` has cell value `aaaaa`.

```
= IFERROR(INDEX(B1:B6,MATCH(1,(A1:A6="aaaaa")*(B1:B6<>"null"),0)),"no match")
```

Note this is an array formula, so you must press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> on the keyboard after typing the formula rather than just pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

To return a similar result except for `bbbbb`, just replace `aaaaa` in the above formula with `bbbbb`.

Comment: Thanks, I will test it. And I will try understand how it works. Never used array formulas before.